# Run Golang script from shell script

Tags: bash, go, automator

I'm trying to run my golang program whenever I log into OSX. I'm trying the following script with Automator:

```
#!/bin/sh
export GOPATH=/Volumes/DTSE9/worker
go run /Volumes/worker/worker.go
```

Whenever I run this with Automator, it tells me `go: command not found`

Comment: So `go` isn't in the PATH. You either add it to the PATH, or us a full path.

Comment: @JimB Do you mean add `export GOROOT=/usr/local/go/bin/go` above the first export? Just tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: No, don't set GOROOT (and that's not a valid value for GOROOT anyway). If `/usr/local/go/bin` isn't in your path, you need to add it to your PATH, or use `/usr/local/go/bin/go run`

Comment: But why not just compile the program and run the executable? It will run faster and won't depend on the state of GOPATH.

Answer (score 3):

Create a file like say `file.go` and it's content should look like:

```
///path-to/bin/go run $0 $@; exit $?

package main

func main() {
    println("Hello World!")
}
```

Then run `chmod +x file.go` and then you can execute it as `./file.go p1 p2`.

**Edit**: This works on Ubuntu. I did not saw that OSX was in question.

This is another version of the first line which does not require the path to the `go` command (tested on zsh):

```
///$(which go) run $0 $@; exit $?
```

Comment: lol, really taking the term "go script" literally, but it is a neat hack ;). It should run fine on macOS too.

Comment: Just tried that and got:
`go: unknown subcommand "./main.go"`
`Run 'go help' for usage.`

Comment: You do not need to call `go` command anymore - just `$ ./main.go`. And I'm using it on Ubuntu; though I'm not familiar with OSX, but since it's a POSIX compatible OS (& as I understand, has bash), this should work on OSX too.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian yeah, that's what I did. `$ ./main.go` and I got the above error message.

Comment: Then it's something about OSX that I'm not aware of (but a guess is at the first line instead of `/path-to/go run` you just have `/path-to/go`).

Comment: `go build` works, but how do I specify the full path when executing an executable? I'm trying `.//Volumes/DTSE9/worker/main`

Comment: @KavehShahbazian Oh I was missing the run. Ok that worked, but how do I specify the absolute path to do the `./`?

Comment: This is the full path to your file. At the first line you should put full path to `go` binary itself.

Comment: @KavehShahbazian No, I mean I'm trying to run a shell script from OSX Automator and the script is on my flash drive, so I'm trying to specify the absolute path for the shell script to execute the go executable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138362/discussion-between-kaveh-shahbazian-and-soubriquet).