# problem to start the local version of the golang tour

Tags: go

i installed go for ubuntu as explained here https://golang.org/doc/install and here https://tour.golang.org/welcome/3 ("When you run the tour program, it will open a web browser displaying your local version of the tour" but it does not)

### works expected:

```
tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.15.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
```

BTW i needed to usa a sudo prefix: `sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.15.3.linux-amd64.tar.gz`

that looks like expected:

```
go version
go version go1.13.8 linux/amd64
go get golang.org/x/tour
```

#### no go files listed (not expected):

then i tried `go run tour.go`

to open the **local version of the tour in a web browser**

and got this errors:

```
$ go run tour.go 
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20190312164927-7b79afddac43
go: extracting golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20190312164927-7b79afddac43
go: finding golang.org/x/tools v0.0.0-20190312164927-7b79afddac43
# command-line-arguments
./tour.go:63:4: undefined: analyticsHTML
./tour.go:63:19: undefined: socketAddr
./tour.go:127:28: undefined: prepContent
m@kubuntu-MS-7C37:~/go/src/golang.org/x/tour$ go run 
go run: no go files listed
```

#### go tool: no such tool "tour"

then i tired `$ go tool tour` got error `go tool: no such tool "tour"` ( https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24819#issuecomment-380777527 )
`

**My Working Environment is Kubuntu 20.04.**

Comment: It doesn't say to `go run tour.go` *or* `go run`. It says to run the file named `tour` that `go get` installed into your `$GOPATH/bin`.

Comment: and how can i start the tour locally?

Comment: i tired `$ go tool tour` got error `go tool: no such tool "tour"` ( https://github.com/golang/go/issues/24819#issuecomment-380777527 )
`

Comment: If the info on that site is faulty, contact the people behind it. This is just a regular bug.

Comment: @hobbs With **$GOPATH** it get `No such file or directory`. `$GOPATH/tour` ==> bash: `/tour: No such file or directory`. `$ $GOPATH/tour/tour`==> `bash: /tour/tour: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `go get golang.org/x/tour`, your tour binary will located at `~/go/bin`.(here ~ means GO_HOME, default is your home folder)

then you can `echo "export PATH=\$PATH:~/go/bin" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`

finally you get what you want below.

```
[x@localhost ~]$ tour
2020/10/26 14:37:17 Serving content from /home/x/go/src/golang.org/x/tour
2020/10/26 14:37:17 A browser window should open. If not, please visit http://127.0.0.1:3999
2020/10/26 14:37:18 accepting connection from: 127.0.0.1:55772
```

Comment: Using the already compiled version `~/go/bin/tour`  works. Some languages can also be started like a script language e.g. `kotlinc hello.kt`. That may not be so easy with go with tour.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`~/go/bin/tour`

We can write a go script, and run it with the go run.
Some languages can also be started like a script language e.g. [`kotlinc hello.kt`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html).
That may not be so easy with go with tour. Better use the binary located at `~/go/bin` .
Helping Links **Writing Scripts with Go**:
[Go code as a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43954643/2891692), [gist: Writing Scripts with Go](https://gist.github.com/posener/73ffd326d88483df6b1cb66e8ed1e0bd)